# Generating multiple AJAX codes for dynamically generated elements in Javascript,

Tags: javascript, ajax, element

I have a script which dynamically generates form elements with their corresponding ID, for e.g.

response from MySQL db says - 4, then

```
<form ID="form0">
<Input>....
<Button type="submit>....
</form>

<form ID="form1">
<Input>....
<Button type="submit>....
</form>

<form ID="form2">
<Input>....
<Button type="submit>....
</form>

<form ID="form3">
<Input>....
<Button type="submit>....
</form>
```

once this list of forms are generated, I have an AJAX code which detects the submit buttons and send the input values off to db via PHP page, something like this below,

```
$(document.body).on('submit', '#form' ,function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var postData = $("#form").serialize();

$.post("../../../functions/processing.php",postData,function(data, status){
  var selectedData = JSON.parse(data);     
  $.each( selectedData, function( i, val ) {
             // do something here...                                           
       });
});
});
```

So my question is that, for the list of forms, I have to somehow generate multiple of this AJAX code for form0, form1, form2, form3.. and because I can't anticipate how many forms will be generated, I can't just write one AJAX code like the one above.. is there anyway to dynamically generate AJAX codes for dynamically generated multiple forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the form a class that identifies it as a form to be handled by your AJAX handler. Then, inside the handler, reference `this` to get the form element that is being submitted.

```
<form ID="form0" class="js-ajax-form">
   <input>....
   <button type="submit>....
</form>
```

Handler

```
$(document).on('submit', '.js-ajax-form' ,function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var postData = $(this).serialize();

    $.post("../../../functions/processing.php",postData,function(data, status){
      var selectedData = JSON.parse(data);     
      $.each( selectedData, function( i, val ) {
                 // do something here...                                           
           });
    });

});
```